# Problem getting response content using Delphi, Indy10 and LARAVEL PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, delphi, indy10

I am building a LARAVEL PHP API in order to be consumed by Delphi 2007.
Basically, in Delphi I am performing a POST and in PHP I am validating the fields. If it fails validation, I need to return code 422 along with the validation errors (array).

In Delphi, I'm using Indy10. In it I have a Client of type `TIdHTTP`.

To do the POST, I do:

```
Client.Post(sFullEndPoint, Request, Response);
```

To get code 422:

```
Client.ResponseCode;
```

To get the content of the response:

```
Response.DataString;
```

In PHP, if I return only one array of errors, as `return $ errors` I can handle it in Delphi with `Response.DataString`, the problem is that I won't know the response code, because it will come 200.
If I return `response ($ errors, 422)` in PHP, Delphi does not find the value of `$errors` in response.

I need to get the HTTP code and the response body. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can set http response code in php like (refrence : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) :

```
http_response_code(422);
```

also in laravel you can do it like :

```
return response('Your output string', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

but i suggest you to pass response as json and add some information about what is wrong or ... :

```
$errors = [
    [
        'error_code'=>1312,
        'error_message'=>'name is empty'
    ]
];
return Response::json($errors, 201); // Status code here
```